# How to remove specific element from ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, forms, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having some trouble with an ng-repeat in a form.

I have form where when I click a button, a group of input fields appear along with a remove button. I am using an ng-repeat for this. I want to be able to remove that specific group of inputs when you click the remove button. The way I have it written right now, though, clicking the remove button removes the inputs from the bottom of the list, no matter where I click. Here's a GIF to better explain it:

[image]

I thought it would just be a simple splice at that specific $index within the ng-repeat, but apparently not (unless there's something I'm missing).

Here is the HTML for the ng-repeat:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">More Parameters</label>
    <button type="button" ng-click="addParameterFields()">Add Parameter</button>
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        <div ng-repeat="params in formData.gameIdParams track by $index" class="controls parameters">
          <input type="text" ng-model="formData.gameIdParams.id[$index]"
            name="gameIdParamsId"
            class="col-sm-3"
            autocomplete="off"
            placeholder="Type of Input"
            validation-field-required="true"/>
          <input type="text" ng-model="formData.gameIdParams.label[$index]"
            name="gameIdLabel"
            class="col-sm-3"
            autocomplete="off"
            placeholder="Placeholder Text to add in Input Field"
            validation-field-required="true"/>
          <input type="text" ng-model="formData.gameIdParams.validationRegex[$index]"
            name="gameIdvalidationRegex"
            class="col-sm-3"
            autocomplete="off"
            placeholder="Regex used for Validation (optional)"
            validation-field-required="false"/>
          <button ng-click="formData.gameIdParams.splice($index,1)">Remove</button>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

And here is the logic I use for adding the forms:

```
$scope.addParameterFields = function() {
  console.log('CLICKED');
  if($scope.formData.gameIdParams === null || $scope.formData.gameIdParams === undefined) {
    $scope.formData.gameIdParams = [];
  }
  $scope.formData.gameIdParams.push({
    id: "",
    label: "",
    validationRegex: ""
  });
  console.log($scope.formData);
};
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a function like :

```
ng-click="removeForm($index)"
```

$index corresponding to the iteration number of your ng-repeat loop.

Then, in your controller, just :

```
$scope.removeForm = function(index){
   delete yourObj[index];
   // or
   yourObj.splice(index, 1);
}
```

**EDIT**

Replace :

```
formData.gameIdParams.your_variable[$index]
```

By :

```
formData.gameIdParams[$index].your_variable
```

Or :

```
params.your_variable
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too, and I'm still getting the same behavior you can see if that GIF I posted. I even have it set to console.log the index just to double check, and the correct index is being displayed. It's still removing from the bottom of the list though.

Comment: Oh ok. Try replacing ALL your ng-models with params.your_variables. Let me know

Comment: AH! I solved it. I'm just a big dummy and wrote my ng-model's incorrectly. In the html I have above I have _ng-model="formData.gameIdParams.label[$index]_ when it should be _ng-model="formData.gameIdParams[$index].label._  It works now.

Comment: Oh indeed ! But tbh, you sould use params.label, it's made for this :) 
i'm gonna edit my answser with yours.